# xpages deleted selected documents: other actions

Tags: view, process, xpages, document

a xpages contain view, and a button with simple action: deleted selected documents

the question: how to insert another action before deleting process, because I need to delete documents on other database.

The docs will be deleted on other database have the same subject the documents will be deleted in view

How to insert another action for it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the desired number of actionGroups. Something like this:

```
 <xp:button value=" My Button" id="button1">
       <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action>
                   <xp:actionGroup>
                        <xp:executeScript>
                            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript://your code in javascript - before the delete method]]>
                            </xp:this.script>                                          
                        </xp:executeScript>     
                    </xp:actionGroup>
                    <xp:actionGroup>
                        <xp:actionGroup>
                            <xp:deleteSelectedDocuments view="viewPanel1"
                                    message="Confirm?">
                            </xp:deleteSelectedDocuments>
                    </xp:actionGroup>
            </xp:this.action>
</xp:button>
```

Comment: The action group process is useful, but in this case, yo'll want to move the confirm action to the CSJS tab. Then it will ask for confirmation before deleting anything. Currently this code would delete from other database, then prompt for deleting selected documents.

Comment: could you help about writing code to the filling "your code in javascript -"??

Comment: Can you give some example in javascript language, example set db to names.nsf and access the view? thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the following code to get a handle to the selected documents in view. No you can delete documents in an other database and after that you can delete the document.

```
var docIds = getComponent("view1").getSelectedIds()
for(var i=0; i< docIds.length; i++){
    var doc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(docIds[i]);

    //Manipulating other documents

    doc.removePermanently(true)
}
```

Comment: where i can put this code? can i put it on javascript above?

Comment: Put it in a button outside of the view and set partial refresh to the view panel

Comment: Poisoned,
what command in javascript to display some value in browser? with pop up dialog?

Comment: Ask your own question and concretize want you want to do

Comment: I tried to display of ListName field, using Alert command. but it doesn't work. Can you help?

var docIds = getComponent("view1").getSelectedIds()
for(var i=0; i< docIds.length; i++){
    var doc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(docIds[i]);

    //Manipulating other documents
    Alert (doc.ListName(0));

}

Comment: poisoned, i have tried your code on my xpages without modification. When i clicked the button, it didn't work (document was not deleted) with error:

Error 500
HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception

Could you please help to solve this? thank you

Comment: You can't use alert() in SSJS. You have to use view.postScript("alert('" + doc.getItemValueString("ListName") + "')") to run CSJS in SSJS. Thins only runs if "ListName" is a single value